# How to cancel an objective?

Tags: tropico-4

I accepted an objective from the religious leader that required issuing an edict.

After looking at the consequences of the edict I decided I want to back out of this. Is there a way to cancel a mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There is no way to cancel a mission.* Either you keep that mission incomplete until the end of the current game, or you complete it.

Think of it this way: some missions give up-front rewards. The Europeans, for instance, may request that you ship a bunch of Lumber, and give you the plans for the Lumber Mill up front.

For edicts that have an effect over time, you can issue the edict and then cancel it. This will undo the faction respect you gain from completing the mission, but at least the mission will be off of your plate. For edicts that have a one-shot effect, you're stuck with the result.

Comment: I was playing the first campaign map. I didn't know the next map would be a fresh start, so it was no big deal in not completing it. Completing it though would have cost me a ton of votes during an election!